# Putting the Information from a SQL Query into a DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datagridview

What would be the best way to display the results of this SQL statement:

```
select "WorkOrder"."WorkOrderID", "Customer"."FirstName", "Vehicles"."Model", "WorkOrder"."State" 
from "WorkOrder", "Customer", "Vehicles"
WHERE "WorkOrder"."VIN" = "Vehicles"."VIN" 
  AND "Vehicles"."CustomerID" = "Customer"."CustomerID"
  AND "WorkOrder"."State" = 'In Progress';
```

I am using C# WinForms with Visual Studio 2010. I can't quite seem to figure out how to put it in a DataGridView or something similar. Is there any way to do or cheat it into a DataGridView?

Comment: You can use it in a `DataTable` and assing it to `DataGridView.DataSource` property. Don't remember to assing `AutoGenerateColumns` to `true`. Take a look at the example from documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How would I go about making one of those?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be put in a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and assing it to [`.DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property like;

```
string command = @"select "WorkOrder"."WorkOrderID", "Customer"."FirstName", "Vehicles"."Model", "WorkOrder"."State"  from "WorkOrder", "Customer", "Vehicles" WHERE "WorkOrder"."VIN" = "Vehicles"."VIN" AND "Vehicles"."CustomerID" = "Customer"."CustomerID" AND "WorkOrder"."State" = 'In Progress'";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    command.Connection = conn;
    using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        DataGridview1.DataSource = table;
        DataGridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, that does not work in my environment. The @ symbol doesn't want to work.

Comment: Also, the string command seems to be interfering with SqlCommand command.